# Azure Cloud Service Publish Fails with "The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request."

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

I can't find much about this error online, one article says it is network related and resolves itself in a few hours but it has been days I still cannot publish to Azure. The exact same configuration worked in the past. What could cause this error?

From the log it seems that the package is uploaded successfully, but then some error is occurring when creating the VM I think. See below. Where would I even begin to look for more details beyond such a simple error message?

```
7:23:17 PM - Connecting...
7:23:17 PM - Verifying storage account 'abc'...
7:23:18 PM - Uploading Package...
7:23:38 PM - Updating...
7:24:09 PM - The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar error, intermittently but not often. It's due to Azure transient error. Retrying will normally help.

```
InternalError : The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request. ---> Hyak.Common.CloudException: InternalError : The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.
15:31:25.937    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
15:31:25.937    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
15:31:25.937    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.DeploymentOperationsExtensions.Swap(IDeploymentOperations operations, String serviceName, DeploymentSwapParameters parameters)
```